# How to type in non-english language in input text box?

Tags: html, dom

I made a form which have an input text and an input submit,My code is working fine but I want to know how to type in hindi or non-english language in input box ? 
Use of input submit is to see what I have typed in input text.

```js
var field1 = document.getElementById('field1');
var resultField = document.getElementById('resultField');

var form = document.getElementById('hindiFont');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
                     
       var x = field1.value;              
                     
       resultField.innerText = x ;   
    
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>checking</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <form id="hindiFont">
    <input type="text" id="field1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>   
    
    <h3 id="resultField"></h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you see the Hindi text because of this encoding here  <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your keyboard settings to type in Hindi.

If just want to test, you can copy paste any Hindi text from internet and paste it in the input box

[image]